# cakeDC search on concat fields

Tags: cakephp

I am using the cakeDC search plugin for cakephp and I need to search by full name. I have stored the name in the database as separate first and last names. How would I concat the first and last name and then perform my search.

So my form input will search either member number or full name.

cakephp version 2.3.5

```
public $filterArgs = array(
    'member_no' => array(
        'type' => 'like' , 
        'field' => array(
            'member_no', 
            'name'
        )
    )
);
```

**Update:**

Here is what it would look like as a sql query:

```
SELECT
   CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName,lastName) AS name
FROM 
   table
WHERE 
   name LIKE '%$keywords%'
```

***Thanks to Mark here is what I added to the Model. All works great now.***

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'name' => 'CONCAT(Member.first_name, " ", Member.last_name)'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the example above in a clean way why not using the plugin as documented? allowing it to do all the work?

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName,lastName)'
);
public $filterArgs = array(
    'search' => array(
        'type' => 'like' , 
        'field' => 'full_name'
    )
);
```

That's all there is to it. Or what is the issue?

Comment: I had this yes, and does work, but because I actually need to search the first_name and last_name combined I used the above thinking I could some how concat the two together

Comment: Combined? How? You only have a single "search" value coming in, right? So its "first_name OR last_name", not both.

Comment: the search term coming in would be the full name: example 'Keith Power', then the database fields first_name (keith) and last_name (power) are combined and the search match's

Comment: that doesnt make any sense. you cannot just split them again. what if the first name consists of multiple strings or double names? Its bad search form design to try it this way IMO.

Comment: I dont want to slpit them. The standard way to store a name is by storing first_name and the last_name. The best way for a user to search a name is with a single search box with using full name. if I split the search box's into first name and last name then when a user searches a name they will get all the 'keith's' and all the 'Power's' when what they were looking for was only the match of 'Keith Power'. I have added what sql would be.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand you now. You need to use a virtual field here. define it in your model and refer it using "field" as displayed above.